# Unable to type text in JTextfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

So, I just wrote a very simple program that has 1 JLabel, 1 JTextField, and 2 JButtons. The problem is JTextField doesn't allow me to enter any texts. I've been thinking really hard about the problem, so any help would be appreciated!

[image: Animated picture]

```
/* Method: init() */
/**
 * This method has the responsibility for reading in the data base
 * and initializing the interactors at the bottom of the window.
 */
public void init() {
    setSize(APPLICATION_WIDTH, APPLICATION_HEIGHT);
    setFont("Courier-24");

    nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
    add(nameLabel, SOUTH);

    nameField = new JTextField(10);
    add(nameField, SOUTH);
    nameField.addActionListener(this);

    graphButton = new JButton("Graph");
    add(graphButton, SOUTH);

    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    add(clearButton, SOUTH);

    addActionListeners();
}

/* Method: actionPerformed(e) */
/**
 * This class is responsible for detecting when the buttons are
 * clicked, so you will have to define a method to respond to
 * button actions.
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == nameField) 
        println("Graph: " + nameField.getText());
    if (e.getSource() == graphButton)
        println("Graph");
    if (e.getSource() == clearButton)
        println("Clear");
}

/* Private instance variables */
private JLabel nameLabel;
private JTextField nameField;
private JButton graphButton;
private JButton clearButton;
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions / or is the field disabled

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala the field is simply disabled, there's no cursor in the text field. I'm not getting any exceptions.

Comment: This `add(nameField, SOUTH);` is going to be a problem, because you've just piled ALL your components into the `SOUTH` position, when it's only meant to hold one...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the reply! I just tried what you said but it still didn't work.

Comment: @HuyenNguyen Are adding all components in a `JFrame` or another class ?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me...

[image: Field]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

/**
 *
 * @author swhitehead
 */
public class JavaApplication1251 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication1251();
    }

    public JavaApplication1251() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        public TestPane() {
            init();
        }

        public void init() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
            add(nameLabel, gbc);

            nameField = new JTextField(10);
            add(nameField, gbc);
            nameField.addActionListener(this);

            graphButton = new JButton("Graph");
            add(graphButton, gbc);

            clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
            add(clearButton, gbc);

//          addActionListeners();
        }

        /* Method: actionPerformed(e) */
        /**
         * This class is responsible for detecting when the buttons are clicked, so you will have to define a method to respond to button actions.
         */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == nameField) {
                System.out.println("Graph: " + nameField.getText());
            }
            if (e.getSource() == graphButton) {
                System.out.println("Graph");
            }
            if (e.getSource() == clearButton) {
                System.out.println("Clear");
            }
        }

        /* Private instance variables */
        private JLabel nameLabel;
        private JTextField nameField;
        private JButton graphButton;
        private JButton clearButton;
    }

}
```

Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: maybe JWindow without (JFrame as) parent, then is true, not answerable without an SSCCE/MCVE

Comment: @mKorbel Agreed, maybe a working example will prompt the OP to provide one which doesn't :P

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution! Btw, can you please point out what is wrong with my original code? Thank you so much!

Comment: @HuyenNguyen *"can you please point out what is wrong with my original code?"* No, because I can't replicate your problem

Comment: I mean I still don't know why for my original code I can't enter text in the text field. Honestly, this is an assignment for an online course that I'm taking, and I don't see I did anything wrong there. Please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HuyenNguyen Unless you can providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, I'm not sure what you expect anybody to be able to do...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just edited my original post and added an animated picture. The Graph and Clear buttons work fine, but when I put my mouse over the text field, nothing happens. Thanks.

Comment: @HuyenNguyen Unfortunately, I can not compile, execute or debug your picture

Comment: I'm sorry. Basically the picture looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/k781mu4s1/